# Is there any way to let this annotation auto-check the Java Method arguments type

Tags: java, annotations

@interface Annotation in java.

If I add @Target(value=ElementType.METHOD),this annotation can be import for Java Method.

Is there any way to let this annotation auto-check the Java Method arguments type?

Something like, I have a method:

```
    @Annotation(type=Integer)
    sayHello(String name)
```

Once I add the customer Annotation, it will auto check the sayHello argument type is match or not,if it is not match,it will cause the compile error.

Is it can be implemented? If, how? Exclude the thought using java Reflect in Runtime to check,this will not fit my idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit - please give an example of a correct invocation and one where the compiler should cause an error?

Comment: @MahdiShabani if I use reflection in Runtime,this will not be auto check.

Comment: @PeterHull this is a idea, you know @Target(value=ElementType.METHOD) will fit all Java Method,but I want to a check, if the Java Method arguments don't match the Annotation definition, it can't be compiled.

Comment: @Sstx Auto check in compile time ?

Comment: So you mean, you want to restrict the methods your annotation can be applied to? So `@Annotation(type=Integer)` can be applied to `void something (int x)` but not to `void another(String y)`?

Comment: I think you will have to write an [annotation processor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to 
(1) make your own annotation processor whose API is provided by `javax.annotation.processing` and `javax.lang.model` packages of JDK which will be invoked during compilation and make necessary checks.
(2) attach it using SPI

(1) For example, given the annotation

```
package aptest;    
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Annotation {
    Class<?> type();
}
```

the annotation processor might look like this:

```
package aptest;
// ... imports
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({"aptest.Annotation"})
public class AnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor 
    implements Processor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
            RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {        
        for (TypeElement te : annotations) {
              for (Element e : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(te)) {
                  // do your checking
              }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

(2) When you package your annotation processor (let's say in aptest.jar) you include `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` file containing the name of you annotation processor class:

```
aptest.AnnotationProcessor
```

And when you compile your code the annotation processor will be invoked. To use it, the command line should like like this:

```
javac -cp aptest.jar SayHello.java
```