# Java - Restrict usage of annotation to certain types of methods?

Tags: java, annotations

I would like to create an annotation that can appear in front of methods which take no arguments.  How can I achieve this?  `@Target` lets me specify `ElementType.METHOD` but does not let me further restrict the types of methods on which the annotation can be applied.

Comment: Refering to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357599/is-there-any-way-to-let-this-annotation-auto-check-the-java-method-arguments-typ?rq=1 you will need a custom annotation processor.

Comment: You may also find useful the type checker framework (JSR 308): http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/